# How can I spread my texture evenly across a cylinder in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: textures, unreal-4

How can I spread my texture evenly across a cylinder in Unreal Engine 4?

Specifically, in the image below, I would like have texture on cylinder (on the left) match the one on the box (on the right). I need a many sides because I want the cylinder to be very smooth.

[image]

Comment: Did you make any changes beyond the scale in the cylinder? Is it Unreal's own, or did you import it from Blender/Maya...?

Comment: You need to search for Triplanar material

Comment: It's unreal own. Just cylinder with many sides and put random texture on it.

Answer (score 1):

generally the texture needs to match the UV you created for it, but if you have a generic object (which looks like is your case) the best bet is to use triplanar material projection, in short is a 3d mapping of a texture, rather than a 2d mapping.

here few links

https://external-preview.redd.it/Llj2OT_QDUjam24PDd0pBauqBDUym4acCiqwRcnPsJI.gif?format=mp4&s=e282639bae4fb0ca5808c819436863bcef83ac99

https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/7147-tutorial-triplanar-material